# Excel LINEST with conditional array and multiple X variables

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, excel-formula

I have a data set formatted as table in Excel 2019. What I would like to achieve is a regression analysis, but only for those records in data set, where we have 'X' in E column which is named IncludeInRegression.

Known Y's are in column F (Price) and known X's are in columns B:D (L, W, Volume).

I have managed to make it work for one independent variable X (variable L in column B) and here is the array formula:

```
    =LINEST(
    INDEX(F:F;N(IF(1;MODE.MULT(IF(tblData[IncludeInRegression]={"X","X"};ROW(tblData[Price]))))));
    INDEX(B:B;N(IF(1;MODE.MULT(IF(tblData[IncludeInRegression]={"X","X"};ROW(tblData[L]))))));
    TRUE;FALSE)
```

However, I cannot make it work for 3 independent variables. I have tried the following array formula, but #VALUE! is returned:

```
    =LINEST(
    INDEX(F:F;N(IF(1;MODE.MULT(IF(tblData[IncludeInRegression]={"X","X"};ROW(tblData[Price]))))));
    INDEX(B:D;N(IF(1;MODE.MULT(IF(tblData[IncludeInRegression]={"X","X"};ROW(tblData[[L]:[Volume]]))))));
    TRUE;FALSE)
```

So it will be easier for you to visualize, I am attaching an image as well.

[image]

Comment: just use INDIRECT: `INDIRECT("tblData["&I4&"]")` instead of `tblData[[L]:[Volume]]` then you would put that in I5, use ctrl-Shift-Enter to confirm and drag over.

Comment: But this will not analyze all X variables at once, but rather each X separately, therefore results will not be correct.

Comment: And you cannot do it, it must be a 1d array and both arrays must be the same size.

Comment: This is not true for LINEST function in case when we do not need conditional arrays of data. Are you trying to say that it is not doable at all?

Comment: Higlight an empty range on the sheet that is 10 rows by 3 columns and put `=INDEX(B:D;N(IF(1;MODE.MULT(IF(tblData[IncludeInRegression]={"X","X"};ROW(tblData[[L]:[Volume]]))))))` (the `)` may be off).  Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Does it return the array you expect?

Comment: No, it returns an #REF! error and this is exactly the issue I would like to solve. If not by MODE.MULT function, maybe some other solution could work. I am pretty sure there must be a way to solve this.

Comment: how about: `=INDEX(B:D;N(IF(1;MODE.MULT(IF(tblData[IncludeInRegression]={"X","X"};ROW(tblData[[L]:[Volume]]))))),0)`?

Comment: You know that Excel has an addon that is already included that will do the regression analysis.

Comment: See [HERE](https://stattrek.com/multiple-regression/excel.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this tool. But I need to build a dynamic model on a certain data set. The example I have provided is just imaginary. In real case, I have historical data of  1 year sales for number of unique products. And for each of these products I would like to have a regression analysis dynamically created... That is, based on drop-down selection of unique product all the X's are set and next I need to include only those records with 'X' into analysis. So this is my last step where I stuck.

Comment: did you try with the `,0` in the third criterion of the INDEX? `=LINEST(
    INDEX(F:F;N(IF(1;MODE.MULT(IF(tblData[IncludeInRegression]={"X","X"};ROW(tblData[Price]))))));
    INDEX(B:D;N(IF(1;MODE.MULT(IF(tblData[IncludeInRegression]={"X","X"};ROW(tblData[[L]:[Volume]]))))),0);
    TRUE;FALSE)`

Comment: Yes I did. This part alone returns a value, but overall results are not correct, totally off.

Comment: I get `1.026841844`, `-0.551879028`, `0`, `27.69162122`.  Those are wrong?  If so then I go back to my original premise that this cannot be done with formula.

Comment: No, the results you have provided are ok, but I do not get the same?!? I got: -0.077822241 50.0654488 #N/A #VALUE!

Comment: Then the data that is coming back from the indexes is wrong.  I had hard coded the values.  now that I understand, let me play with it.  It may take a while.  I will let you know what I find.

Comment: Appreciate it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include another array of the column numbers in the second INDEX so it returns all three columns:

```
=LINEST(
INDEX(F:F,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(tblData[includeinRegression]={"X","X"},ROW(tblData[Price])))))),
INDEX(B:D,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(tblData[includeinRegression]={"X","X"},ROW(tblData[[L]:[Volume]]))))),N(IF(1,{1,2,3}))),
TRUE,FALSE)
```

Depending on ones version this may need to be array entered by selecting four horizontal cells, putting the formula in the formula bar and using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when leaving edit mode

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like charm:)

Comment: It may take me a while to get it through my thick head, but when it does....

Comment: Just one more short question... Why is it required to reference full columns in the INDEX function, like for example F:F and B:D? Why I am not allowed to use table structured reference, like tblData[Price]?

Comment: you can but then you would need to make the adjustment to the fact that the MMULT returns the actual row number and not the relative row.  So it is possible but makes the formula much more complicated and should be weighed against the advantages of using full table structures.  If your table is fairly static in those columns I would leave it. If your table moves around a lot then it may be worth the pain.

Comment: Understood. Thanks again.